# hide joomla login page after login

Tags: joomla

i have link mysite/login (hidden menu item, for guests only) to page with login form.
After login i redirecting users to main page and hide this link.
After that, appears 2 login form (for registered users only) on top of the site, with logout option.
But if i press "Prev page, button in browser" after login i see empty page - mysite/login.

how to hide this page for guests after login ? or redirect away from this page.

you can try it on my demo site http://bolomsa dot com/ 
demo/demo

Comment: Try refreshing the page and it will show the logout button. The issue is that the old page is in the browser cache. There is not really a reason to worry about this unless you think your users will do browser back.

Comment: i need to hide this page

Comment: Define what you mean by hide. If they type in the url do you want them to get a 404 when they go there or a you are not allowed or something? Is there something on tha page you don't want them to see?  Why not just make the menu link have an access level of guest?

Comment: i want to redirect from empty page, when registrated users press back in browser. thx for idea - set this menu link for guests and redirect to main with 404.php )

Comment: No you should not redirect to the home page with a 404, it's not a 404, that was a joke that was supposed to sound ridiculous. Also it won't work since it is just loading from browser cache not not from the server.

Comment: i accessed level of guest for link to login page and if users will press back after login they will see beautiful 404 page with link to main page )))